# How can you retrieve (read) GitHub secrets without invoking CI?

Tags: github, github-actions, secret-management

Github has a functionality called ["Secrets" made for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions) (which is their CI).

These secrets are easy to read from the CI. You can do it like this,

```
env: # Or as an environment variable
  super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
```

And then the runner can do anything with them. But it seems weird if they're that easy to get to a runner, that it's impossible to get them out without a runner.

You can set them in the [back of GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions?tool=webui), or with [`gh` the GitHub CLI tool](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions?tool=cli). Is it possible to read the value of a GitHub Actions Secrets without intentionally leaking them from a runner.

---

A follow up to this question [How can I easily leak secrets with GitHub Actions?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/18901/18965)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No

It's not currently possible to view the value of the secret without leaking the secret, which is easy enough.

There is a [ticket for this functionality in the CLI, and it was closed.](https://github.com/cli/cli/discussions/3397)