# How can I easily leak secrets and read the value with GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions, secret-management

GitHub actions seems to block out both the secret, and the base64 dump of the secret. Is there any easy way to dump all of secrets, or a list of secrets, from GitHub Actions? I need to be able to read (view) the value of one?

---

This is a follow up to [How can you retrieve (read) GitHub secrets without invoking CI?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/18896/18965)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using a simple shell script

This is one such method to it, which will output a script that when run on the terminal will dump all the secrets collected. This uses [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) to transliterate the characters in the secret, which is sufficient to get past the GitHub secret protection.

```yaml
name: Secret Leak
on: [push]

jobs:
  Leak-Secret:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set env with secrets         
        env:
          SECRET_NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          SECRET_AWS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.AWS_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          export LC_ALL=C;
          echo "tr 'A-MN-Za-mn-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m' <<EOF";
          env | sed -ne's/^SECRET_//p' | tr 'A-MN-Za-mn-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m';
          echo "EOF";
        shell: sh
```